# Prove that f is a constant function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

My friend asked me for help on the following question:
If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Z$ is a continuous function, prove that $f$ is a constant function.

I tried the following proof, but I am generally bad at writing proofs, so I would like to know if the following is acceptable:

**Proof**
Suppose $f$ isn't constant, then $\exists x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $x_1 \ne x_2$ and $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$.
Note that $f(x_1)$, $f(x_2) \in \mathbb Z$.
Assume, without loss of generality, that $f(x_2) > f(x_1)$. 
Then $f(x_2) - f(x_1) \ge 1$ and so $f(x_2) > f(x_2) - 0.5 > f(x_1)$.
But $f(x_2) - 0.5 \not\in \mathbb Z$, so $\not \exists x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = f(x_2) - 0.5$.
By the Intermediate Value Theorem this means that $f$ isn't continuous; a contradiction.
Therefore $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. I would just write:

Suppose $f$ is not constant, then there is $a>b$ with $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Let $y\in [f(a),f(b)]\cup [f[(b),f(a)]$ be a number that is not an integer. By the intermediate value theorem there is $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x)=y\not\in \mathbb Z$. Contradicting that the co-domain of $f$ is $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to the other people who answered too; I appreciate the in depth answers!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer works, but you can also use the real-analysis definition of continuity.  Specifically, suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is continuous and let $y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Using the induced topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, we know that $\{y\}$ is both open and closed (it is a closed point and it is the intersection of the open set $(y-.5,y+.5)$ with $\mathbb{Z}$).

Since $f$ is continuous, the preimage of $\{y\}$ is both open and closed.  The only sets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  Since there is some point $y'\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y'$ is in the image of $f$, it must be that the preimage of $\{y'\}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

One version of the Intermediate Value Theorem just says the image of a connected subset of $\mathbf R$ is connected. Now in a discrete topological space, the only connected subsets are points. Hence the image of $\mathbf R$ is a point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be a point where the function $f$ changes value from $n_1$ to $n_2$. Then no matter how close we move to $x$ we always have a gap of $|n_1-n_2|$. Or in mathematical terms: For $\epsilon<|n_1-n_2|$ there doesnt't exist $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. By the analytic definition of continuity this proves that $f$ cannot be continuous.